# Separating Area Code from Phone Number - iOS

Tags: ios, regex

How can I parse out the area code from any given phone number? For example, if I enter in `208-399-2777`, the 208 is the area code in the United States. However, in Brazil, the phone number `78 5239-6822` has a 2-digit area code.

Does `NSTextCheckingResult` provide any of this functionality?

Comment: What about US numbers in the form `(208) 399-2777` or local numbers like `555-1212`. Given that vast number of phone number formats around the world, this may be quite difficult.

Comment: @rmaddy agreed, this is not a trivial problem. Just out of curiosity, can local numbers be mobile numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure. Where I live has been 10-digit dialing for all calls since I got my 1st cell phone. If you live in an area with 7-digit dialing and your cell phone has a similar number, the area code may not be needed to call into the same area.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your problem where tinkering with the string may not work and you may want to know more about the area code, check out Google's libphonenumber https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/, there is a wrapper for Objective C https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the first "set" of numbers in the phone number string

```
NSString *pattern = @"^\\d+";
NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern
                                                          options:0
                                                          error:nil];
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` matches the beginning of a string
- `\d+` matches one or more numbers

**Note:** If your phone numbers are formatted without spaces (e.g., `1234567890`) it will not work.